# Is there a way to read the urls from packets recieved in C?

Tags: c, http, url, networking, tcp

I have been using lpcap and successfully received packets Which come in and out of my computer.

However, I've only been able to get the HostName and the IP addresses of the source of each of those packets and not necessarily the URL associated with them.

For example, I will run my code and see a source IP, and then Google for example I would see 74.125.226.163 and lga15s45-in-f3.1e100.net as opposed to google.com.

I have been receiving TCP packets and got the prior information from the IP header information.

I have read prior that frequently the AVP in HTTP headers contains this information, however I don't know how to get these HTTP headers from the TCP information or if there even is a way using lpcap.

Bottom line is there a way to read the url from where my packets are originating?

Included some code for reference.
My Processing Method:

```
void processPacket(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr* header, const u_char *packet) {
    const struct ip_hdr *ip;
    const struct eth_hdr * eth;
    char* src;
    char* dst;
    char src_host[NI_MAXHOST];
    char dst_host[NI_MAXHOST];
    eth = (struct eth_hdr*)(packet);
    ip = (struct ip_hdr*)(packet+SIZE_ETHERNET);
    src = inet_ntoa(ip->ip_src);
    dst = inet_ntoa(ip->ip_dst);
    memset(src_host, 0, NI_MAXHOST);
    memset(dst_host, 0, NI_MAXHOST);

    getDNS(inet_ntoa(ip->ip_src), src_host);
    getDNS(inet_ntoa(ip->ip_dst), dst_host);
    printf("Eth Dest Host: %s\n", eth->eth_destHost);
    printf("Eth Send Host: %s\n", eth->eth_sendHost);
    printf("Source: IP: %s Host: %s\n", inet_ntoa(ip->ip_src), src_host);
    printf("Destination: IP: %s Host: %s\n", inet_ntoa(ip->ip_dst), dst_host);
}
```

And here is my collection method

```
int collect(pcap_t *handler, char* device, char* conditions) {
    struct pcap_pkthdr pkthdr;
    const unsigned char *packet = NULL;
    char* args = (char*)malloc(32);
    int count = 0;
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    bpf_u_int32 netaddr = 0, mask=0;

    //prepping conditions for collection
    memset(errbuf, 0, PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE);

    if (device == NULL) {
        printf("Error device not found exiting...");
        return -1;
    }

    //stores network address and mask in netaddr and mask, exits if not found
    if (pcap_lookupnet(device, &netaddr, &mask, errbuf) == -1) {
            printf("Error net address and mask not found exiting...");
            return -1;
    }

    //opens the session allowing all net traffic to be read, exits if it cannot
    handler = pcap_open_live(device, MAXBYTES2CAPTURE, 1, 512, errbuf);
    if (pcap_lookupnet(device, &netaddr, &mask, errbuf) == -1) {
            printf("Error opening session exiting...");
        return -1;
    }
    if (conditions != NULL) {
        printf("Implementing Filter...\n");
        if (startFilter(conditions, handler, mask) == -1) {
                printf("Error initializing Filter");
                return -1;
        }
    }

    //executing collection
    printf("Starting loop...\n");
    pcap_loop(handler, -1, processPacket, (u_char*)&count);
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Do you understand the relationship between TCP and HTTP? Have you been able to read the value of the "Host" attribute in the HTTP header?

Comment: I haven't been able to read the Host attribute in the HTTP header, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: You didn't answer my first question. If the answer is "no", then you have some reading to do.

Comment: I do understand the basic difference between TCP and HTTP, I'm just slightly confused on how to read from a HTTP header.

Comment: Is there a way to reconstruct the TCP stream to create some sort of HTTP header information?

Answer (score 0):

> For example, I will run my code and see a source IP, and then Google for example I would see 74.125.226.163 and lga15s45-in-f3.1e100.net as opposed to google.com.

What you're asking for is impossible. Nothing states that the reverse DNS lookup of an IP address has to match the domain name originally used in the forward DNS lookup to get the IP address in question:

That is because `google.com` may resolved to a huge number of IP addresses for load balancing and geographic distribution reasons.  So there is a one-to-many relationship from a domain name to IP addresses.

However, each of these IP addresses (tied to a particular webserver, or load balancer) still has a unique identity on the internet, which is evidenced by its reverse lookup. So there is (usually) a one-to-one relationship from an IP address to its reverse DNS lookup.

Check out this example:

```
C:\Users\Jonathon>nslookup
Default Server: 192.168.1.1
Address:  192.168.1.1

> google.com
Server:  192.168.1.1
Address:  192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    google.com
Addresses:  2607:f8b0:4009:800::1007
          173.194.46.68
          173.194.46.69
          173.194.46.70
          173.194.46.71
          173.194.46.72
          173.194.46.73
          173.194.46.78
          173.194.46.64
          173.194.46.65
          173.194.46.66
          173.194.46.67

> 173.194.46.68
Server:  192.168.1.1
Address:  192.168.1.1

Name:    ord08s11-in-f4.1e100.net
Address:  173.194.46.68
```

Another example is shared hosting servers, where one physical machine (and thus public IP address) is used to serve many websites with different domain names.

An example:

```
Forward lookup of several domains:

    example-01.com  --\
    example-02.com  ------> 127.64.23.17
    example-03.com  --/

Reverse lookup:

    127.64.23.17  ----> 23-17.www.some-isp.example.com
```

Comment: I realize that I was just trying to go through my process, I'm really asking if there is a way to find out the URL associated with the packet I am gathering.
Thank you for your response and your help.